# Snap cannot create user data directory: Not a directory

Tags: snap

My PC fails to run snap packages, when I try I get:

```
2021/07/31 20:56:38.255535 cmd_run.go:576: WARNING: XAUTHORITY environment value is not a clean path: "/mnt/e664d184-8567-4278-93ce-c986567c66af/home/iaquobe/.Xauthority"
cannot create user data directory: /home/iaquobe/snap/shapezio/2: Not a directory
```

The directories do however exist.
So far the packages I tested are `0ad` `shapezio` `whatsdesk`, all of them had the same issue.

Those packages do run on my laptop.
One thing that is different is that on my PC `/home/iaquobe` is a symbolic link to a drive at `/mnt/[...]/home`.

This is the only cause for this error I could think of, what do you think?
And what could I do to fix it?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `/home` symlink is indeed causing the issue. This is a known snap bug (or to be more precise [design limitation](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/limitations-in-snapd/9718) of snap) -- with snap packages home can't be a symlink or a different directory than `/home`, see [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/snappy/+bug/1620771) for details. Suggested workaround/fix is to run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure apparmor` but some people in the bug discussion said it didn't help so it might not work.

Answer (score 2):

We use domain with realm, so our path home is not `/home`, instead `/home/MYDOMAINCOMPANY/`. I fixed by editing `/etc/apparmor.d/tunables/home.d/ubuntu` with that line:

```
@{HOMEDIRS}+=/home/MYDOMAINCOMPANY/
```

After save, just restart some services:

```
systemctl restart apparmor.service snapd.apparmor.service snapd.service snapd.socket
```

That way I can run at many computers by script or using Ansible.

Comment: It is also possible to list multiple directories: `@{HOMEDIRS}+=/home/MYDOMAINCOMPANY/ /home/`